# How to change boolean variation on document template

Tags: content-type, document-template, variations, choice-field

I've a bool (checkbox field) as a template field, and it shows true - if checked - and false - if not - on the template field content and I want to show up different display text.

what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert  > quick part > field

with IF formula:

```
IF [MyField] = "true" "MyTrueText" "myFalseText" \* MERGEFORMAT
```